# I need a suitable app to transfer contacts from outlook to salesforce automatically

Tags: contact, migration, connect-for-outlook

I have to connect emails to salesforce , so that the contacts will be migrated to salesforce from emails (outlooks)
I would like to find out which apps are suitable for this 
I need a way that any new contact in outlook will be automatically transfer to salesforce

Comment: What have you looked at?  What limitations have you found?  There are a lot of tools, including ones supplied by salesforce, that could help.

Comment: one of the limitations is that I need an option for using Outlook for Pop3 servers not Microsoft Exchange Server or Microsoft Office 365

Answer (score 0):

I see that there are apps on appexchange in Order to achieve your requirement for automatic email & contacts integration